# SELECT between today and yesterday

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I'm trying to select between two dates like this:

```
SELECT p.Code, p.Name, sum(h.PA = 1) AS PA, sum(h.PB = 1) AS PB, 
    sum(h.PG = 1) AS PG, sum(h.GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'GF') AS GF, 
    sum(h.GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'SB') AS SB, sum(h.GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'VIA') AS VIA,
    sum(h.Blanco) AS Blanco
FROM psthostess p 
LEFT JOIN `psttodo-uit` h 
    ON h.`Hostess Code` = p.Code 
    AND DATE(h.`afgewerkt tablet datum`) BETWEEN CURDATE() 
    AND (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE p.Indienst = 1 GROUP BY p.Code, p.Name
```

But I don't get any results.

I want the results of today and yesterday. But when I do this

```
SELECT *
FROM `psttodo-uit` p
WHERE DATE(p.`afgewerkt tablet datum`) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

or change `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` into `CURDATE()` I get results... How does this come?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
WHERE p.`afgewerkt tablet datum` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
      AND p.`afgewerkt tablet datum` < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Assuming current date and time is: April 11, 2014 05:30PM, the datetime you need is between
*April 10, 2014 00:00:00* and *April 11, 2014 23:59:59* (inclusive)

```
CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY => April 10, 2014 00:00:00
CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY => April 12, 2014 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select *  from  emp where joindate between SUBDATE(NOW(),1) and NOW();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you please provide some commentary as to what it is doing